# jQuery listview double scrollbar (sometimes)

Tags: jquery-mobile, scrollbar

I hope anyone can help me. I've a jQuery mobile page and I get two scrollbars after an ajax callback that calls a changePage

```
$.mobile.changePage('#page_with_listview');
```

On the pageshow event for **page_with_listview** I do an $.AJAX lookup and in the success callback I fill the listview and trigger a refresh:

```
$('#my_listview').listview('refresh')
```

The result I get (not every time):

[screenshot of the result (I'm not allowed to post images yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH2QG.png)

Does anyone have a clue on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and making sure I included the jquery mobile css after my own style from themeroller solved it. something like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-style.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" />
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-style.min.css" />
```

Comment: If this doesn't solve the issue, then at least it should be a good starting point, since the symptoms are exactly the same